# Table inserting as NULL values when using springboot with spring Data JPA in save method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to save my form data into database table drivers. And using springboot with spring Data JPA . By using .save() method, database is inserting as null values. But not showing any error. I am adding my controller fie below,

```
DriverRepository driverRepo;


@RequestMapping(value="/driverSubmit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView driverSubmit(@ModelAttribute Driver driver, Model model) 
    {
        model.addAttribute("driver", driver);
        driverRepo.save(driver);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dHome"); //to home page after insertoin 
    }
```

Comment: did you checked if driver object has values? What means inserting as null? You will save a new driver in the db but not values? Please describe your problem more.

Comment: I am submitting a form. By giving action "/driverSubmit".When I am accessing values through @RequestParam method, It getting properly. But I need the above method for receiving submitted object and need to save to database

Comment: I already know what you are doing. But have you checked by debugging if `dirver` really maps the values your are sending? And again -> What means inserting as null? You will save a new driver in the db but not values?

Comment: Yes sir, My object getting as null in my controller. Is there any definition mistake I done here.Now I just Started learning with spring , spring boot and data JPA. I need to explore more in basis of CRUD operation.

Comment: can you show your driver object and the request body of your submitting form. There is any mapping issue.

Comment: Can You check my below comment answer?

Comment: Changed tags, since from the comments it seems clear that it is related to the form submit not being resolved into a Driver object

Comment: **Hint**: Entity has attributes with names like `name`, `age`, etc., whereas form fields are named `dname`, `dage`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test your api from swagger or postman first, and debug the code first whether you are getting values in your driver object or not. If you are getting the data in driver properly then it must be some error coming out of your form request from UI. I guess an entry of driver object is getting created in db but all the values are getting saved according to their default initial values.